# Open a specific URL in a specific user profile in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

For streamlining my workflow I'm trying to open a specific url (say a specific google sheet) in a specific user profile (say there are 5 user profiles on my chrome, and I want to open the one that is called 'b' for instance) in Google Chrome.

Any options/workarounds for this?

I'm on macOS Sonoma - 14.4 Beta

Thanks!

Now, I've tried creating a shortcut, that does open the 'application' - Google Sheets with the specific user but it doesn't open the specific URL.

I've also tried Keyboard Maestro — I use a Mac) — to record a macro to open the exact url but somehow that's also not triggering.